# I can't see the stroke from a rectangle with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I can't see the stroke from the rectangle. When I create a circle or a triangle, I can see the stroke but when I create a rectangle I can't see it.

This is the code for the rectangle.

```
context.beginPath();
context.fillStyle = "White";
context.fillRect(470,300,50,50);
context.lineWidth = 3;
context.strokeStyle = "black";
context.stroke();
context.closePath();
```

This is the result that I get right now..
[image]

Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: Update your question to include a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem, preferrably in a runnable code snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `context.strokeRect(x,x,x,x);` will allow you to see the stroke.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
   </canvas>

<script>
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var context = c.getContext("2d");
context.strokeRect(20, 40, 150, 100);
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.strokeStyle = 'green';
ctx.strokeRect(20, 10, 160, 100);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```